Find rows without duplicates in columns
I have a large table [MasterTable] with 31 columns. For each [TrackID], there are 5 rows, all identical except two columns, [ResultFK] and [ParamFK], linked to two other tables.
My end goal is to extract [ResultFK] and [ParamFK] into another linked table, so [TrackID] becomes the primary key.
However, I am finding some records have different data in columns that should be identical.
I want to select ALL the rows of a [TrackID] that have any differences in any column, except [ResultFK] & [ParameterFK].
I'm using SQL Server.
Sample (not all columns listed):



TrackID
CountryFK
CRLFK
CorineLUFK
SubTypeFK
ProvidedFK
GridTypeFK
ResultFK
ParamFK




FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
155
6
1847
6


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
155
6
17035
8


FR_Soil
11
1
35
14
155
6
37456
9


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
170
7
5147
10


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
170
7
32656
14


IT_Soil
12
3
14
25
143
8
2341
4


IT_Soil
12
3
14
25
143
8
2741
8


IT_Soil
12
3
14
25
143
8
2345
7


IT_Soil
12
3
14
25
143
8
229
3


IT_Soil
12
3
14
25
143
8
231
9



Desired result: I need to pull all the records for that TrackID to pass to my colleague, so they can determine which of the values is correct.  For example, SubTypeFK may need to be all 13 or all 14.
I don't necessarily need to list all 31 columns, only those columns with differing values.  but I don't know which ones they will be unless they are included in the query.



TrackID
CountryFK
CRLFK
CorineLUFK
SubTypeFK
ProvidedFK
GridTypeFK
ResultFK
ParamFK




FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
155
6
1847
6


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
155
6
17035
8


FR_Soil
11
1
35
14
155
6
37456
9


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
170
7
5147
10


FR_Soil
11
1
35
13
170
7
32656
14




FYI SSMS is purely a UI, its not the database engine. Usually the UI you are using isn't relevant to the question.

OK, got it.  I'm self taught and, until recently, only worked on Access.  I've been thrown into the deep end with a massive SQL project and am very quickly teaching myself about SQL server and all that goes with it.

This method gives you the data you need, just not in the format you showed in your question. You could pivot the results back out again but the results here maybe suitable for your needs anyway.
DECLARE @masterTable TABLE (TrackID varchar(10), CountryFK INT, CRLFK INT, CorineLUFK int, SubTypeFK int, ProvidedFK int, GridTypeFK int, ResultFK int, ParamFK int)
INSERT INTO @masterTable VALUES
('FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 155, 6, 1847, 6),
('FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 155, 6, 17035, 8),
('FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 14, 155, 6, 37456, 9),
('FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 170, 7, 5147, 10),
('FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 170, 7, 32656, 14),
('IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2341, 4),
('IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2741, 8),
('IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2345, 7),
('IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 229, 3),
('IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 231, 9)


SELECT 
    TrackID, Property, Count(*) as PropertyValueCount
    FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT TrackID, Property, PropertyValue
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT TrackID, CountryFK, CRLFK, CorineLUFK, SubTypeFK, ProvidedFK, GridTypeFK 
                    FROM @masterTable
            ) m 
            UNPIVOT(
                PropertyValue for Property IN (CountryFK, CRLFK, CorineLUFK, SubTypeFK, ProvidedFK, GridTypeFK)
            ) as UnP
    ) n
    GROUP BY TrackID, Property
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1

This gives us the following results.



TrackID
Property
PropertyValueCount




FR_Soil
GridTypeFK
2


FR_Soil
ProvidedFK
2


FR_Soil
SubTypeFK
2



Here's a dbfiddle you can use to test it.
All we're doing here is, starting in the middle and working outwards...
Get a distinct set of all columns (except the ResultFK and ParamFK columns)
Take this unpivot it
Then get a distinct list of TrackID plus the new columns from the unpivot - Property (column name originally) and PropertyValue.
Finally, we group by TrackID and property and return only those with a count >1

That would be helpful.  It would identify those records with issues. Excuse my ignorance, but this manually lists values INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES...  I have several million records.

@SallyC That part just creates some sample data to demostrate so the code works, in your real code, you already have a mastertable, so you just select against that

@SallyC, as siggemannen points out that's just to generate the sample data. You only need the select statement. Just swap out the @masterTable for your real table name. You'll also have to include all the columns (except ResultFK and ParamFK) in the column list that is in the UNPIVOT part.

You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark it as answered (the check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This will help other SO users find answers to similar questions in the future.

Thanks, this did work, to a point.  I tested it on just those columns I gave you, but when I added the rest of the columns I got an error.  It was my mistake to only give you INT columns, when there are a mixture of nvarchar, INT, float and a single smalldatetime.  I get "...conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list"

Having said that, I see that I can get around this by repeating the query for each PropertyType.

As you are only counting instances of values, then you could still do this in a single query. In the SELECT DISTINCT part, just cast each column to a common datatype (e.g. ... , CAST(CountryFK as varchar(256)) AS CountryFK, CAST(CRLFK as varchar(256)) AS CRLFK, ... etc...  This way, everything is converted to a single datatype so the UNPIVOT() operator will work as before.

Got it.  Thank you again.

If you want something quick and dirty, you can use for json to create a "hash" value of your columns, something like this:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  t.*
    ,   MIN(x.json) OVER(partition BY TrackID) AS hashvalueMin
    ,   MAX(x.json) OVER(partition BY TrackID) AS hashvalueMax
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 155, 6, 1847, 6)
        ,   (N'FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 155, 6, 17035, 8)
        ,   (N'FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 14, 155, 6, 37456, 9)
        ,   (N'FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 170, 7, 5147, 10)
        ,   (N'FR_Soil', 11, 1, 35, 13, 170, 7, 32656, 14)
        ,   (N'IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2341, 4)
        ,   (N'IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2741, 8)
        ,   (N'IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 2345, 7)
        ,   (N'IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 229, 3)
        ,   (N'IT_Soil', 12, 3, 14, 25, 143, 8, 231, 9)
    ) t (TrackID,CountryFK,CRLFK,CorineLUFK,SubTypeFK,ProvidedFK,GridTypeFK,ResultFK,ParamFK)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  [key], value
        FROM    OPENJSON((SELECT t.* FOR json path, without_array_wrapper,include_null_values)) t
        WHERE   t.[key] NOT IN ('TrackID', 'ResultFK', 'ParamFK')
        ORDER BY [key]
        FOR json path
        ) x (json)
    ) x
WHERE   x.hashvalueMin <> x.hashvalueMax

This part turns every row into a json where only the "interesting" columns are part of the final string:
FROM    OPENJSON((SELECT t.* FOR json path, without_array_wrapper,include_null_values)) t
        WHERE   t.[key] NOT IN ('TrackID', 'ResultFK', 'ParamFK')
        ORDER BY [key]
        FOR json path

For stability i include ORDER BY [key], this is so the final json will have keys in same order.
include_null_values might not needed, but i added it just in case.
Finally to compare i create two columns: hashValueMin + hashValueMax over the TrackID "window".
WHERE   x.hashvalueMin <> x.hashvalueMax outputs where things differ.
The same technique can be used to generate different column values, but this exercise is left for the reader. I usually just put this stuff in excel + vlookup and conditional formatting which highlights the different columns.
